# Finding the number of occurences strings in a specific format occur in a given text

Tags: c#, .net, regex, string, .net-2.0

I have a large string, where there can be specific words (text followed by a single colon, like "test:") occurring more than once. For example, like this:

```
word:
TEST:
word:

TEST:
TEST: // random text
```

"word" occurs twice and "TEST" occurs thrice, but the amount can be variable. Also, these words don't have to be in the same order and there can be more text in the same line as the word (as shown in the last example of "TEST"). What I need to do is append the occurrence number to each word, for example the output string needs to be this:

```
word_ONE:
TEST_ONE:
word_TWO:

TEST_TWO:
TEST_THREE: // random text
```

The RegEx for getting these words which I've written is `^\b[A-Za-z0-9_]{4,}\b:`. However, I don't know how to accomplish the above in a fast way. Any ideas?

Comment: Do they always occur in order? Could there be a `TEST:` after the first `word:`?

Comment: They don't have to be in order.

Comment: Can you clarify the example to include a case for when you have other text and multiple special words on the line (assuming that is allowed)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regex is perfect for this job - using Replace with a match evaluator:

This example is not tested nor compiled:

```
public class Fix
{
    public static String Execute(string largeText)
    {
        return Regex.Replace(largeText, "^(\w{4,}):", new Fix().Evaluator);
    }

    private Dictionary<String, int> counters = new Dictionary<String, int>();
    private static String[] numbers = {"ONE", "TWO", "THREE",...};
    public String Evaluator(Match m)
    {
        String word = m.Groups[1].Value;
        int count;
        if (!counters.TryGetValue(word, out count))
          count = 0;
        count++;
        counters[word] = count;

        return word + "_" + numbers[count-1] + ":";
    }
}
```

This should return what you requested when calling:

```
result = Fix.Execute(largeText);
```

Comment: return word + "_" + numbers[count-1] + ":"; <- There is something wrong with this line, as I get an error "Index was outside the bounds of the array." with it.

Comment: Actually, disregard the above comment. I fixed some issue with your code (string word = m.Value instead) and it seems to work now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, regex is not necessary here.

You can split your large string by the `':'` character. Maybe you also need to read line by line (split by `'\n'`). After that you just create a dictionary (`IDictionary<string, int>`), which counts the occurrences of certain words. Every time you find word x, you increase the counter in the dictionary.

**EDIT**

1. Read your file line by line OR split the string by `'\n'`
2. Check if your delimiter is present. Either by splitting by `':'` OR using regex.
3. Get the first item from the split array OR the first match of your regex.
4. Use a dictionary to count your occurrences.

   `if (dictionary.Contains(key)) dictionary[key]++;`
   `else dictionary.Add(key, 1);`
5. If you need words instead of numbers, then create another dictionary for these. So that `dictionary[key]` equals `one` if key equals `1`. Mabye there is another solution for that.

Comment: I should use regex though, because a) these words only occur at the beginning of a line in the large string (hence the ^ in the regex) b) These words are WHOLE words and c) They are 3 or more letters long. Also, how would I edit the strings to add the "_ONE", "_TWO" or whatever number to them?

Comment: @david: That is more of a reason to not use regex, since the format is so fixed (text ending with a `:` -- just use string indexing). This can be done exactly as @MatthiasKoch says. If you want it to be fast, don't use regex when you don't have to.

Comment: @bobbymcr: My main concern is that they are whole words and can be of any casing, and string functions don't deal with those to my knowledge.

Comment: If you have `string line` representing the line, all you need to do is check `!string.IsNullOrEmpty(line)` and then `line[line.Length - 1] == ':'`. Now you know that `line.Substring(0, line.Length - 1)` must be your word.

Comment: I forgot to mention that apart from the word, there can be other text on the line. :s

Comment: How do you know which words are the ones you want to append with a number? Please edit and clarify your question.

Comment: Okay, if `':'` is your delimiter then read your file line by line. Try to match the line with your regex (delimiter) OR use `Split` appropriate and check if the array is of length > 2. Then take the first item from the array.

Comment: @bobbymcr: With the regex I posted at the end. It gets all of the words I need, however I have trouble appending the number to them because I need to figure out how many of each word occurs.

Comment: @MatthiasKoch: So I should split the text with '\n', loop through all of the lines and then add matches to an array? I'm confused, how would that help me identify how many times a specific word occurs, and which number I have to append to them?

Comment: Alright, I think I get what you mean. I'll try and see if I can figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

i think you can do this with Regax.Replace(string, string, MatchEvaluator) and a dictionary.

```
Dictionary<string, int> wordCount=new Dictionary<string,int>();
string AppendIndex(Match m)
{
   string matchedString = m.ToString();
   if(wordCount.Contains(matchedString))
     wordCount[matchedString]=wordCount[matchedString]+1;
   else
     wordCount.Add(matchedString, 1);
  return matchedString + "_"+ wordCount.ToString();// in the format: word_1, word_2
}


string inputText = "....";
string regexText = @"";

   static void Main() 
   {
      string text = "....";
      string result = Regex.Replace(text, @"^\b[A-Za-z0-9_]{4,}\b:",
         new MatchEvaluator(AppendIndex));
   }
```

see this:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/cft8645c(v=VS.80).aspx

Comment: Oh, I see. However, there is a small problem, garbage is returned instead of the number when the function is called, and it appears after the colon instead of before.

Comment: Hmm, it appears there was a problem on your line "return matchedString + "_"+ wordCount.ToString();// in the format: word_1, word_2". It should have been wordCount[matchedString].ToString(), but apart from that it seems to be working.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this example (I know it's not perfect and not so nice)
lets leave the exact argument for the Split function, I think it can help

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  string a = "word:word:test:-1+234=567:test:test:";
  string[] tks = a.Split(':');
  Regex re = new Regex(@"^\b[A-Za-z0-9_]{4,}\b");
  var res = from x in tks
  where re.Matches(x).Count > 0
  select x + DecodeNO(tks.Count(y=>y.Equals(x)));
  foreach (var item in res)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(item);
  }
  Console.ReadLine();
}

private static string DecodeNO(int n)
{
 switch (n)
 {
   case 1:
     return "_one";
   case 2:
     return "_two";
   case 3:
     return "_three";
  }
 return "";
}
```

Comment: think tthis is very maintenance-intensive.

Comment: You are using Linq, and I mentioned in my post that I am using NET 2.0, so this won't work for me (if you're wondering why I still stick to NET 2.0, it's because I have to port my app to Linux later onwards, but that's besides the point).